# Dynamically ALTER a SQL Table based on a DataTable

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am getting data from a rest feed at regular intervals and want to copy this into a SQL table. Easy enough using SQLBulk copy.
The issue i am struggling with is that the fields I get from the feed could change and i want to be able to add any new columns dynamically to the table. Any columns that no longer exist i need to leave in the table. I can simply add those into the datatable.

My question. What options do i have to do this. Is there any free 3rd party .net frameworks that will do it or how can i write this manually.
Must all be done in .NET.

Thanks

Comment: It is a bad idea to alter table columns based on what you get in a 3rd party message. You should think about saving the message as it is in a table field or try to understand more about the structure of the 3rd party message and design your tables to cater to highest complexity and lowest complexity of the message.

Comment: It is a bad idea to alter your table. Structure your table to take XML or JSON and query it accordingly.

Comment: If you really must ignore the semantic content of the new fields, then use an Entity-Attribute table (aka *property bag*) to store the new fields and values: Schliemann

Answer (score 0):

as you stated that you are getting data from a rest feed then u can create a simple ASP WebPages Application

Add a page in which you are going to call the "Rest Feed".
Now what format the Rest Feed is offering
mostly JSON is used

you can parse JSON to a Model Class which corresponds to the data structure of that feed

then simply insert the data using SQLConnection , SQLCommand to the underlying database

here is a sample code which you can alter

```
string siteContent = string.Empty;
string url = "http://www.RESTFEEDURL.com";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using(Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
using(StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
{
    siteContent = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
//NOW PARSE THE DATA AND SEND TO DATABASE HERE
//data is in siteContent

//now you want to decode the data and get all the column names
var keyArray = Ext.Object.getKeys(Ext.JSON.decode(siteContent));

//if suppose data has following format
//{"ID":"1","name":"google","IP":"69.5.33.22","active":"true"}
//{"ID":"2","name":"bing","IP":"70.5.232.33","active":"false"}
console.log(keyArray);
// ["ID","name","IP","active"]

now 
foreach(var item as keyArray)
{
sql = "IF COL_LENGTH('TABLENAME', item) IS NULL alter table [TABLENAME] add [item] int default 0 NOT NULL"
//run this sql query using sql command and see the magic
}
```

Comment: I am already reading the data and am already adding the data to a database table. The issue i have is how can i alter the database table if i need to add in extra columns.